Lookup an ID in multiple columns - Excel
I have an initial table that looks like this:



Values
IDs




Value 1
159, 91


Value 2
846, 1, 751


Value 3
34



I could make it look like:



Values
IDs






Value 1
159
91



Value 2
846
1
751


Value 3
34





and I have another (empty) table that looks like this:



IDs
Values




751



159



34



1




I want the end result to look like:



IDs
Values




751
Value 2


159
Value 1


34
Value 3


1
Value 2



I'm not sure what formula to use to fill in the table.
My data set has 83.9k rows and if I convert table 1 into table 2 i get 2k columns.
I tried match w index - but it's not working due to the large data set. I was thinking of using search, but still haven't figured it out.

index() with match(), check on here to find examples of use across multiple columns.

most of the answers worked for fewer rows, but it kept crashing - I ended up doing it in python (i didn't try the more complex answers, only the ones with cell formulas)
IDS_exploded = IDS.assign(MPM=IDS['MPM'].str.split(', ')).explode('MPM')
output = MPM.merge(IDS_exploded, on='MPM', how='left')
output = output.sort_values(by=['Internal']).copy()
output = output.drop_duplicates(subset='MPM').copy()

If you use a function like REDUCE() for that many rows of data it will always crash and not just that the work will be delayed. Good Luck!

Here is one alternative way using XLOOKUP() function :


=XLOOKUP(1,1-ISERR(FIND(", "&D2&", ",", "&$B$2:$B$4&", ")),A$2:A$4)


Or, can use the following to spill for the whole range using MAP() or BYROW():
=MAP(D2:D5,LAMBDA(α, 
 XLOOKUP(1,1-ISERR(FIND(", "&α&", ",", "&B2:B4&", ")),A2:A4,"")))


However, using POWER QUERY will be the easiest and neat approach when dealing with larger datasets:


To perform the above task, follow the steps:

First convert the source range into a table and name it accordingly, for this example I have named it as Table_1 and Table_2 respectively.



Next, open a blank query from Data Tab --> Get & Transform Data --> Get Data --> From Other Sources --> Blank Query



The above lets the Power Query window opens, now from Home Tab --> Advanced Editor --> And paste the following M-Code by removing whatever you see, and press Done


let
    SourceOne = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table_1"]}[Content],
    Split = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(Table.TransformColumnTypes(SourceOne, {{"IDs", type text}}, "en-US"), {{"IDs", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(", ", QuoteStyle.Csv), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "IDs"),
    DataType = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Split,{{"Values", type text}, {"IDs", Int64.Type}}),

    SourceTwo = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table_2"]}[Content],
    Merge = Table.NestedJoin(SourceTwo, {"IDs"}, DataType, {"IDs"}, "DataType", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    Custm = Table.AddColumn(Merge, "Values_Output", each [DataType][Values]),
    Expand = Table.ExpandListColumn(Custm, "Values_Output"),
    Remove = Table.RemoveColumns(Expand,{"DataType"})
in
    Remove





Lastly, to import it back to Excel --> Click on Close & Load or Close & Load To --> The first one which clicked shall create a New Sheet with the required output while the latter will prompt a window asking you where to place the result.


Secondly, if you are splitting the ID's into column wise in the source then you could try the any one of the following as well, but not the efficiency may vary :


• One Using TEXTJOIN()
=TEXTJOIN(",",1,IF(F2=B$2:D$4,A$2:A$4,""))


• Second Using CONCAT()+REPT()
=CONCAT(REPT(A$2:A$4,F2=B$2:D$4))


• Third Using TOCOL()+IFS() or IF():
=TOCOL(IFS(F2=B$2:D$4,A$2:A$4),2)



Updated 2024-08-08: without REDUCE
On large data sets, vertical stacking with REDUCE seems to cause crash or performs very slowly. Here's an attempt avoiding repeated vertical stacking.
It takes about 1.5 seconds (down from about 10 seconds from the previous method) on my Mac with a data set of 90K. Thanks to DjC for suggesting the improvements.
Method
Using TEXTBEFORE/TEXTAFTER instead sped up the calculation. If lookup is needed, use the sorted table with binary lookup for faster results.

Get row and col matrix for the ids
SEQUENCE(ROWS(data)) & id_delim & SEQUENCE(, max_split_per_row)
Get ids and values by MAPping through
ids, --TEXTSPLIT(INDEX(data, r, 2), id_delim)
IF(item = "id", INDEX(ids, 1, c), INDEX(data, r, 1)),NA())
Name the cell with this formula, for example id_lookup

=LET(
    comment_1, "Instead the whole col (f.ex. B:B), set to a suitable max",
    last_data_cell, $B$90000,
    data, $A$2:INDEX($B$2:last_data_cell, COUNTA($B$2:last_data_cell)),
    id_col, TAKE(data, , -1),
    id_delim, ",",
    cols_per_row, LEN(id_col) - LEN(SUBSTITUTE(id_col, id_delim, )) + 1,
    col_indices, SEQUENCE(, MAX(cols_per_row)),
    ids, TEXTBEFORE(
        TEXTAFTER(id_delim & id_col & id_delim, id_delim, col_indices),
        id_delim
    ),
    hstack_, HSTACK(
        --TOCOL(ids, 2),
        TOCOL(IF(cols_per_row < col_indices, NA(), TAKE(data, , 1)), 2)
    ),
    SORT(UNIQUE(hstack_), 1, -1)
)

Look up ids with:
=LET(
    comment, "-2: binary search on lookup_array sorted in descending order",
    r, G2:G10,
    IF(
        ISBLANK(r),
        "",
        XLOOKUP(
            r,
            INDEX(id_lookup#, , 1),
            INDEX(id_lookup#, , 2),
            "not found",
            ,
            -2
        )
    )
)



this would've been great and it works - but not for the 84k rows :( it crashes

@ilia, please give the latest one a try. It is significantly faster and doesn't crash on my 90Kx5 data set.

A big thanks to @DjC for reviewing and suggesting improvements.


Formula in E2:
=XLOOKUP("* "&D2:D5&",*"," "&B2:B4&",",A2:A4,,2)

